# Adding new user roll in WordPress that can only add custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have purchased this theme  http://pixelgeeklab.com/wp-realestast/#all and would like to add new user roll in wordpress so visitors can register to the website and add their own estates.

I tried manually coding this but realized thah is a LOT of work and I tried using the members plugin by Justin Tadlock (http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)

My problem is that I can enable only ALL posts to be viewed and edited but can't edit so that visitor can only have access to custom post type called ESTATES.

Underneath find the code from functions.php (I tried a lot, so if someone could see this and clear the code, I would be very grateful):

```
 add_action('init', 'wptuts_getrole');  

function wptuts_getrole() {  
    $role = get_role('seller');  
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($role);  
    echo '</pre>';
}  

add_action( 'init', 'ct_add_role' ); 
function ct_add_role() {

 $role = get_role( 'seller' );
 $role->remove_cap('edit_posts');
     $role->add_cap('read');
     $role->add_cap('manage_options');
     $role->add_cap('publish_posts');
     $role->add_cap('add_estates');
     $role->add_cap('edit_estate');

/*add_role('seller', 'Seller', array(
    'read' => true,
    'add_posts'=> false,
    'publish_posts' => false,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'delete_posts' => false,
    'add_estate'=> false,
    'manage_options'=>false,
));*/
//}
```

And the code from estates.php:

```
 /**
 * #####################################
 * Actions
 * #####################################
 */
static function register() {
    $args = array(
        'labels'       => array(
            'name'          => 'Estates',
            'singular_name' => 'Estate',
        ),
        'description'  => __( 'This post type is used in RealEstast theme', PGL ),
        'public'       => TRUE,
        'show_ui'      => TRUE,
        'hierarchical' => FALSE,
       /* 'capability_type' => 'post',
        'capability' => array(
            'add_posts' => 'add_estates',
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_estates',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_estates',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_estates',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_estates',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_estates',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_estates',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_estate',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_estate',
            'read_post' => 'read_estate',
        ),*/
        'supports'     => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail',
        ),
        'has_archive'  => TRUE,
        'rewrite'      => array(
            'slug'       => 'estate',
            'with_front' => TRUE
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'estate', $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this plugin, it should do everything you need http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/